# Getting an Error on Node.js Postgresql user authentication

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I keep getting an eerror when trying to create user auth with express
this is the error

Executing (default): SELECT "id", "companyName", "password", "email", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."email" = 'testing@testing.com';
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","companyName","password","email","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'test','$2a$10$5zE8XFLAo8JxCqEqj7ELC.Zo.tFPINCgW6pf/WkpqrhDPEkTYPFaS','testing@testing','2020-07-10 04:56:43.081 +00:00','2020-07-10 04:56:43.081 +00:00') RETURNING *;
/Users/ThaylieNguyen 1/Desktop/Projects/EntrepreneurCRM/server/controllers/usersController.js:36
if (err) throw err;
^

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

```
const signup = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password || !req.body.companyName) {
        res.status(400).send({ msg: "Please pass the required information." });
  } else {
      User.findOne({
            where: {
                email: req.body.email,
            },
      })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            return res
              .status(400)
              .json({ email: "a user is already registered with that email" });
          } else {

            const newUser = User.create({
                                  email: req.body.email,
                                  password: req.body.password,
                                  companyName: req.body.companyName
                            })

              bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  newUser.password = hash;
                  const payload = {
                    id: newUser.id,
                    email: newUser.email,
                    companyName: newUser.companyName,
                  };
                  newUser
                    .save()
                    .then((user) => {
                      jwt.sign(
                        payload,
                        keys.secretOrKey,
                        { expiresIn: 3600 },
                        (err, token) => {
                          res.json({
                            success: true,
                            token: "Bearer " + token,
                          });
                        }
                      );
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
                });
              });
          }
        });
  }
};
```

Comment: It says error in line 36 from file "usersController.js:36" can you please point which line it is here? Is this start of the else statement?

Comment: Its the line after bcrypt.hash, wheere the if statement start @GnanasekarS

Comment: Sorry, Is this issue resolved already? @jojo_1215